# speed of "import module" in embedded python

Tags: python, performance, import, module, labview

I wrote a piece of prototype python code using some handy scipy functions for image processing, and it was embedded in C, which just wrapped the py code into a dll, so that it was used by another program.

Now I have got all the wrapping and communication to work, but I noticed that every time the dll is used, "import scipy" and "import numpy as np" will take some fraction of a second to go through. The situation is pretty bad since I intend to use the dll in a loop.

Is there a way to avoid repetitive importation of modules, or make the dll static, or use some client-server model, but in which case how does ndarray object handled?

Thanks for your thoughts!

-E

PS: what I am really doing with this big detour is try to use the python code in labview, which does not interface with python directly (unlike with matlab). I am aware of labpython, which i don't think handles ndarray, and i don't think it's a live project any more, unfortunately.

Comment: I have called Python code from LabVIEW using Cython. The end result is essentially a DLL including an `init` function for a python module and custom functions (defined with`cdef public` in cython) that can called from LabVIEW. The cython code can include module imports. There has to be some python initialization when the LabVIEW program is started and some finalization at the end.

Comment: The obvious answer would seem to be, as you say, a client-server model. What is the problem with passing ndarray data between LabVIEW and Python? Is there any reason you have to embed the Python code in a C dll rather than simply running it in Python?